# Using mailto in a standalone|fullscreen web application on iPhone

Tags: mailto, iphone-standalone-web-app

I am developing a mobile web application and want to add the ability to send an e-mail from the web application using a link with the href="mailto:..." attribute.  I coded the link and tested it and it works fine in IE 10 running on a Desktop.  Next I tested on Safari running on an iPhone and it also works fine, as long as the web application is run in Safari.  But, if I add that same web application to the home screen and run it as a fullscreen application from the home screen, pressing the mailto button has no effect.  I want the ability to open the default e-mail application on the iPhone if the user clicks the link if the web application is in standalone/full screen mode.  Is there a way to do this and if so how?

```
<a href="mailto://subject=Emailed Document from Server&body=test">E-Mail</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is resolved as of iOS 7.0.3.